# How to implement try-catch in bash scripts using bash-oo-framework?

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

I have come across `bash-oo-framework`, which as lot of utilities. But there is minimal documentation on usage. Can you guys help with an example of using try catch and exception utilities of bash infinity framework?

Comment: There seems to be example usage in the README: https://github.com/niieani/bash-oo-framework#using-try--catch Did you bump into issues with that example?

Comment: I didnt understand exceptions utility part. I understand try catch.